# Почему не срабатывает форма заявки?

Tags: php, форма

Всем привет.
Помогите с формой заявки на html + php. Я в php почти не разбираюсь...
Есть форма:

```html
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="th-contact-form ajax-contact" data-bg-src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/bg/feature-bg1.png">
                    <div class="form-title">
                        <h3 class="page-subtitle h4 mb-30 mt-n1">Оставьте заявку</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="form-control style2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control style2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Регион" class="form-control style2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 form-group">
                            <textarea placeholder="Сообщение" class="form-control style2"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 form-group mb-0">
                            <input type="submit" class="th-btn fas fa-arrow-right ms-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

И обработчик на php:

```
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR empty($number) OR empty($subject) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Пожалуйста отправьте форму повторно";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "mail@key-word.ru";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $subject";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Спасибо за вашу заявку!";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Что-то не так, пожалуйста отправьте заявку повторно.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

?>

После отправки формы ничего не происходит... Может кто знает как заставить форму работать?
P/S: сайт лежит на боевом хостинге.

Comment: как минимум, в инпутах нет атрибутов name. плюс сделать вывод ошибок. И в целом отладка, по ссылке из прикрепленного сообщения